# Why isn't some resource maxed out to 100% during Visual Studio compile?

Tags: performance, visual-c++

I'm compiling a large solution of about 100 C++ projects with Visual Studio.  During compilation, neither Memory, CPU, Disk, nor Ethernet are utilizied to anywhere near 100% (according to the Task Manager Performance tab).  CPU is often as low as 25% and Memory Disk utilization seems to be as low as 5-10%.

So if no resource is utilized at 100%, what's the bottleneck?  What's limiting my compile speed?  I was honestly expecting it to be CPU.  But it seems that it's not.

Am I perhaps measuring incorrectly?  What should I expect to be the limiting resource when compiling?  How can I speed things up?  If there's something else that is the limitation (like RAM but as I/O via a cache or something) then what's the right tool/method to measure the bottleneck?

**Additional Info:** I'm certainly using *maximum number of parallel projects to build* = 8.  Also *multi-processor compilation* is enabled for all the Visual C++ projects.  My machine has 8 logical processors.  So I really think that I'm not just maxing out one core.  That would present itself as 12.5% usage on my machine, (and I see that often with single-threaded applications.)

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/CRLzESV.png

Comment: 25% on a 4-core machine could mean that one core is fully occupied. Have you enabled [multiprocessor compilation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/02/14/vcpkg-recent-enhancements/) or [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385193.aspx)?

Comment: I have just tried to rebuild a single C project with some 100 files. It took 25s. The Multiprocessor option had no big effect (below 5%). On my 8-core machine, 4 cores were active, but none of them near 100%. Overall utilization stayed around 25%. So, your question is justified.

Comment: My machine is 8 core.  And parallel builds and multi-threaded compilation are indeed enabled.  See my "Additional Info".

Answer (score 1):

well memory wise maybe your application don't use as much memory.

and as for the CPU usage, your program might be working on one thread, or to be more specific, on one single core of your CPU;

so if you have a quad core CPU, your application won't use anything above 25%.

as for the internet usage, i think that the task manager shows you computer's Ethernet capability, so maybe you have an internet speed of 10 Mb/s, but your Ethernet is capable of 50 Mb/s.

this is a link that i just looked up :https://askleo.com/why_wont_my_program_use_more_than_25_of_the_cpu/

great question.

Comment: It's 8 core.  So the 25% does not come from a single core maxing out.  Parallel builds are enabled (8) and multi-threaded compilation is enabled.  So I don't think that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Just setting the compilation to run all projects in parallel you just get the same result as @VasiliyGalkin, too much work for your setup.

But due to the way VS compiles each project you need a certain overlap so limit the number of parallel projects to 2-3 depending on the actual PC you run it on. If your PC is a monster with 16+ cores you might be able to go 1-2 up. You might be happy about the result or find that it doesn't fully use your CPU due to other limits in VS.

[This](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/03/22/make-vc-compiles-fast-through-parallel-compilation/) article gives an in depth analysis of why its slow, the conclusion is that you need to set up your compilation to fit VS idea of the world.

A brief of the article

I would guess your setup is something like

> Multiprocess compilation off

Giving you the following performance

[image]

Setting it to on and setting

> enable minimal rebuild off

Gives you

[image]

Still for one project because your compilation times for your units is like this

[image]

Due to different compilation flags / precompiled headers see article for more. Fixing it gives you something like

[image]

and the 3 progression after each other

[image]

Now add max project 2 or 3 to use all capacity.

Ideally VS should have offered an option of using X threads so the problem would mostly go away as no more threads are started than usable and it would just pick the next task from the next project when there are free resources.

Answer (score 0):

Memory is very unlikely to become a bottleneck for the compilation. Normally it's CPU-intensive process. The fact that your CPU is used for 25% instead of 100% may indicate that your projects are compiled sequentially using 1 core out of 4.

Try to check the "maximum number of parallel builds" in Visual Studio menu **Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run**.

You may find the screenshots attached to my [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45379427/how-to-limit-the-number-of-parallel-cl-exe-processes-during-the-visual-studio-so) related to similar topic, but opposite problem - too much going in parallel instead of too little :)

Comment: Parallel builds are definitely enabled.  Set to 8.  Multi-threaded compilation is enabled too.  So it's not a 1 out of 4 single-threaded thing.